# Email check with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax-forms

I tried to make Ajax form and tried to make email verification there. I found this solution
http://jsfiddle.net/EFfCa/

but can't turn it on in my script:

```
<script> 
    $('#joinForm').ajaxForm(function() {
        var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        var name = $("input[name=name]")
        var email = $("input[name=email]")
        if(name.val()==''||email.val()=='') {
            $(".notify").show();
            $(".notify p").text('empty');
        } else if(testEmail.test(email.value)) {
            $(".notify").show();
            $(".notify p").text('email is wrong');      
        } else {
            $(".notify").show();
            $(".notify p").text('good');    
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

The form always passed verification even email is wrong. Verification for empty fields works good...

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @yarons No errors. But form passed verification even email is wrong. Verification for empty fields works good...

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by a "wrong" email? What emails have you passed to it that you believe the verification should reject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line `else if(testEmail.test(email.value))` will return true if the email is correct.

In your logic that's where the email is wrong could that be the problem?

Comment: Thx... I need to be more attentive. There was comment about  to change `.value` to `.val()` also. Thanks for that too...

Answer (score 1):

This is because your passing `email.value`. `jquery` objects don't have a parameter called `value`, so this will resolve as `undefined`.

`.test()` returns true if it is passed undefined, so your test will always pass.

use `.val()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('input').blur(function() {
        var testEmail =/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        if (testEmail.test(this.value)) alert('passed');
        else alert('failed');
    });
```

Comment: Please consider adding a little explanation on how your code snippet does answer the question so the OP can learn from your code.